# Array member of a struct is not assignable

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to implement the autograd algorithm in C using
the graph data structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    struct variable *var;
    double grad;
} node;

typedef struct {
    double value;
    double grad;
    bool requires_grad;
    node *parents[];
} variable;

variable *init_variable(double value, double grad, bool requires_grad, node *parents) {
    variable *new_variable;
    new_variable->value = value;
    new_variable->grad = grad;
    new_variable->requires_grad = requires_grad;
    new_variable->parents = parents; // Error happens here, "Array type 'node *[]'  is not assignable"
    return new_variable;
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error that is displayed by the
LSP. And I am fairly new to the language and the concept of pointers so please bear with me.

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Given that `variable *new_variable;` is a pointer to a `variable` structure, just which `variable` structure do you think it points to?

Comment: Are you sure flexible array member is really what you need there?

Comment: @SergeyA can you tell me how can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole arrays are not assignable in C.  Moreover, your `variable.parents` is a flexible array member, which is almost surely not what you want, and in any case, the corresponding pointer type is `node **` and you are trying to assign an object of type `node *` to it.

Also, declaring ...

> ```
>     variable *new_variable;
> ```

... declares only a pointer, not anything for it to point to, nor does it assign a valid pointer value.

> How could I fix this issue?

It depends on what you want to achieve.  Here is some valid code that is related to your original, but it is unclear to me whether it does what you want it to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    struct variable *var;
    double grad;
} node;

typedef struct {
    double value;
    double grad;
    bool requires_grad;
    node **parents;     // NOTE: type change
} variable;

variable *init_variable(double value, double grad, bool requires_grad,
        node **parents) {  // NOTE: type change

    // NOTE: dynamic allocation (incurs an obligation to free)
    variable *new_variable = malloc(sizeof *new_variable);

    if (new_variable) {
        new_variable->value = value;
        new_variable->grad = grad;
        new_variable->requires_grad = requires_grad;
        new_variable->parents = parents;  // NOTE: matching types
    }
    return new_variable;  // returns a null pointer if the malloc failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays cannot be assigned to.  However, you can change the definition of the `parents` member to have type `node *` to match the parameter and use that.

```
typedef struct {
    double value;
    double grad;
    bool requires_grad;
    node *parents;
} variable;
```

Also, you don't initialize `new_variable` before attempting to dereference it.  This will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and most likely result in a crash.

You need to allocate space for it:

```
variable *new_variable = malloc(sizeof *new_variable);
```

Comment: `node *parents;` is likely wrong. OP seems to need array of pointers to nodes.

Comment: @SergeyA Given OP's stated inexperience with C and with pointers, I'm inclined to think the parameter type is correct, not the original member type.

Comment: @dbush, could you point me towards finishing the init_variable function?

Comment: @BrymerMeneses The above changes should address the problem.

Comment: @dbush but *parents* is plural, and one can expect to have multiple "parents" in a graph. I think, OP needs a (dynamic) array.

Comment: @dbush I think SergyA's right...OP wants to create a graph, so if a node can have an arbitrary number of "parents" (directed edges), and we want to reference the parent nodes, not duplicate them, then node** is the necessary type.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the data member `var` in this structure definition

```
typedef struct {
    struct variable *var;
    double grad;
} node;
```

does not have the same type as the type `variable` defined in this typedef.

```
typedef struct {
    double value;
    double grad;
    bool requires_grad;
    node *parents[];
} variable;
```

In this typedef there is declared an unnamed structure with the alias name `variable`. `variable` and the type `struct variable` are two different types.

Instead you should write

```
typedef struct variable {
    double value;
    double grad;
    bool requires_grad;
    node *parents[];
} variable;
```

This structure has a flexible array as its data member

```
    node *parents[];
```

You need to allocate separately memory to this data member when you are creating an object of the type `variable` depending on the potential size of the flexible array.

In this function

```
variable *init_variable(double value, double grad, bool requires_grad, node *parents) {
    variable *new_variable;
    new_variable->value = value;
    new_variable->grad = grad;
    new_variable->requires_grad = requires_grad;
    new_variable->parents = parents; // Error happens here, "Array type 'node *[]'  is not assignable"
    return new_variable;
}
```

you are using uninitialized pointer `new_variable` that has an indeterminate value. So the function invokes undefined behavior. Also array do not have the assignment operator. So this statement

```
new_variable->parents = parents;
```

is in any case incorrect.

You need to allocate dynamically an object of the type `variable` with allocation the flexible data member `parents` of the required size.

If you mean a scalar data member instead of the flexible array in the definition of the structure `variable` then you need to declare it like

```
node *parents;
```